# The application has stopped unexpectedly: How to Debug?

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, adb, logcat

Please note, unlike many other questions having the subject title "application has stopped unexpectedly", I am not asking for troubleshooting a particular problem.

Rather, I am asking for an outline of the best strategy for an Android/Eclipse/Java rookie to tackle this formidable task of digesting huge amounts of information in order to develop (and debug!) a simple Android application.

In my case, I took the sample skeleton app from the SDK, modified it **slightly** and what did I get the moment I try to run it?

> The application 
>   (process.com.example.android.skeletonapp)
>   has stopped unexpectedly. Please try
>   again.

OK, so I know that I have to look LogCat. It's full of timestamped lines staring at me... What do I do now? What do I need to look for?

Is there a way to single-step the program, to find the statement that makes the app crash? (I thought Java programs never crash, but apparently I was mistaken)

How do I place a breakpoint?

Can you recommend an Android debug **tutorial** online, other than [this one](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)?

Comment: Copy-n-paste the lines from your logcat output to the question so people can help point you in the right direction. In general look for the word 'Exception' and a callstack or any references to your application.

Comment: @typo.pl Thanks, I will definitely do that when I know what I am doing. At this point, however, I am only interested in methodology as @HappyCodeMonkey and @jqpubliq suggested.

Comment: I gave you methodology - "logcat output - look for the word 'Exception' and a callstack or any references to your application". Don't waste time enabling/disabling breakpoints in the debugger when  Android has already told you where the big problem is in your app - the Exception and callstack are the smoking guns.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm an Eclipse/Android beginner as well, but hopefully my simple debugging process can help...

You set breakpoints in Eclipse by right-clicking next to the line you want to break at and selecting "Toggle Breakpoint". From there you'll want to select "Debug" rather than the standard "Run", which will allow you to step through and so on. Use the filters provided by LogCat (referenced in your tutorial) so you can target the messages you want rather than wading through all the output. That will (hopefully) go a long way in helping you make sense of your errors.

As for other good tutorials, I was searching around for a few myself, but didn't manage to find any gems yet.

Comment: This is a great answer. I tried right-clicking next to the line I want to break at and select "Toggle Breakpoint" but I couldn't find any such menu item. Are you sure you are not confusing Eclipse with Visual Studio? :)

Comment: click inside of a method. The left side should have a blue highlight for the scope of that method. That is where you click. a double click is equivalent

Comment: Nope, definitely Eclipse...though, looking at it again, is it possible you're clicking on the file editor itself rather than the beige-colored area right along the left side of the file editor? (For example, this is the area where the small warnings show up to tell you you need to import a package or whatever). I'd be happy to create a screenshot if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9):

Filter your log to just Error and look for FATAL EXCEPTION

Comment: This is a great tip. Thanks! (and +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Logcat display inside the 'debug' perspective in Eclipse the lines are colour-coded.  It's pretty easy to find what made your app crash because it's usually in red.

The Java (or Dalvik) virtual machine should never crash, but if your program throws an exception and does not catch it the VM will terminate your program, which is the 'crash' you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your app has the needed permissions.I was also getting the same error and I checked the logcat debug log which showed this:

```
04-15 13:38:25.387: E/AndroidRuntime(694): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:555-555-5555 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{44068640 694:rahulserver.test/10055} (pid=694, uid=10055) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

I then gave the needed permission in my android-manifest which worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

1. From the Home screen, press the Menu key.
2. List item
3. Touch Settings.
4. Touch Applications.
5. Touch Manage Applications.
6. Touch All.
7. Select the application that is having issues.
8. Touch Clear data and Clear cache if they are available. This resets the app as if it was new, and may delete personal data stored in the app.

Comment: This wouldn't help in debugging a problem with an app. It may be a work around for a problem, but that doesn't help with determining what was going wrong.

Comment: The question asks for a strategy for debugging, not necessarily getting rid of the error